# Hypothesis testing with 1 or 2 sample in ornithology

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design

I am doing an experiment with birds. I have set up the experiment to measure how certain foods affect bird flying speeds. When I implement a control, for example food A, I want to claim that the average flying speed of Gulls is higher when they are fed with food A. I set up the 2-sample hypothesis, but I'm confused whether to compare food A with the average (include food A) or compare food A with the average (exclude food A, ie. all other foods). I really appreciate if anyone could enlighten me on this topic.

Edit: Thanks for @ReneBt suggestion, I will make the experiment more clear. All gulls are fed with the same controlled diet. They are randomly selected to get food supplements A and B. Food A and food B were added in their diet but only one supplement for one bird throughout the experiment. I want to test the claim that the average flying speed of Gulls is higher when they are fed with food A. Hope it's clear.

Comment: Welcome to CV, I hope it can be helpful to you. Anyone answering this is in danger of providing misleading advice even when answering correctly as the question is very ill defined. Is food A a supplement to a wild foraging diet? Or are all gulls captive and all groups receive highly controlled diets? In short the inclusive comparision (A in both groups) makes no sense. As to what exactly is sensible depends on your precise design and aim.

Comment: Thank you @ReneBt for your response. So sorry if I wasn't clear on the experiment. Let me make it clearer. All gulls are fed with the same controlled diet. They are randomly selected to get food supplements A and B. Food A and food B were added in their diet but only one supplement for one bird throughout the experiment. I want to test the claim that the average flying speed of Gulls is higher when they are fed with food A. Hope it's clear. Thanks again.

Comment: @Taddy2019: Can you please add this new information as an edit to the post? Not everybody read comments, so that way your probabiliy of getteing a good answer increases.

Comment: Thank @kjetilbhalvorsen for your suggestion. All done.

Comment: How many birds in each group? Can you post (a link to) the data or some plot of the data?